# Should I interview for a job I didn't apply for? Manager from another company contacted me for interview but I didn't apply for a job

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, linkedin

I was contacted by a senior level engineer at another consulting company. We have "connections" on linked in. His email asked if I had any interest in his company and wanted to interview.

This is surprising and flattering and I am very interested in a job with him because I am trying to get back to Colorado where we have family.

But I didn't apply for a job and he is not forthcoming with any job description. He wants a phone interview but I don't know what I am interviewing for.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace Stack Exchange! I think you will find you will get more positive responses if you phrase this in the form of question.  Also it is helpful if the question isn't too specific and primarily opinion based.  Questions are most helpful when they help many people.

Comment: You can not take the job if you don't like it.   What is the big deal?

Comment: It's most likely a quick phone screen that doesn't commit the interviewer to anything.

Comment: Most "cold calls", whether from agents or direct from companies, are nonsense. But it doesn't hurt to ask for more detail. Personal peeve: I will not accept vagueness in how they got my name; if they aren't willing to tell me who suggested they call or how they found out a out me, I'm not willing to talk to them. Trust has to go both ways.

Comment: If it is a consulting company then they might not want to give details unless you talk to them first because they don't want you to bypass their company if you figure which company they are consulting for. So there might not be any devious motive other than that in not giving details. Since you want to go back to Colorado then you have nothing to lose by talking to the person. Worst case, you get some interview practice at the expense of some of your time.

Answer (score 13):

The word 'interview' can be very loaded. It doesn't have to mean a full on three hour session with multiple stake holders. It can just be an informal chat to see if you may be useful to each other, now or in the future.

**It's only a phone call. What do you have to lose?**

Sometimes there may not be a concrete role. They may just be sounding out to see if they can fit you anywhere. Roles can be built around people, if they would benefit the company.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is normal in industry nowadays. This can happen to anyone. It is possible that you described some details about your past and current projects on LinkedIn, and HR or a manager from another company has seen it. If they found this information helpful for their organization, they can contact you with a job offer.

You can ask them about the detailed job description with a pay/benefits package. Also, you can ask them about the role and responsibilities they want to give you. This will make it easier for you to respond them.

So, as per my opinion, communicate with them to resolve your queries. You can also check the organization's details on their company website or social media presence. You can easily get basic details about the company and current openings in it on the internet. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

There is no harm in attending an interview, but Without a job description (and salary package), how do you know what you are even applying for?  How do you even prepare for an interview, let alone knowing what they want to employ you to do?  Without a job description and an indicative salary, you will be flying completely blind into an interview situation.  I would be more concerned as to *why* they don't which to supply this up front.

Nonetheless, as discussed in comments, you can still attend and make this an information session for you as well as for them.  However, without some details I would be very wary about actually *accepting* something :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I suppose I should approach it is an informational interview and not get my hopes up. Maybe I am interviewing them?

Comment: @Jason There is no harm in attending an interview, but I'd be careful of going further without any details as to the job.  Asking lots of questions is an excellent idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to lose by keeping open minded and having an exploratory conversatiin.  Sometimes better opportunities can have a unique way of finding us in the market.  I would talk to them and consider why they targeted you and see for yourself if it is a potential area of interest.  Good luck!